pg_basebackup error: connection to server, no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection
There are similar posts and answers to my issue, however they could not help me.
I am using PostgreSQL v16.3 and the latest version of Docker.
I am creating a very basic PostgreSQL cluster using a primary and replica server and deploying on two VPS servers (same region) using Docker Swarm.
Primary server
I created the replicator user with or without password to test both situations. I am using the command GRANT to give full access to replicator user:
# CREATE USER replicator WITH REPLICATION;
CREATE USER replicator WITH REPLICATION ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'replicator_password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE $POSTGRES_DB TO replicator;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA $POSTGRES_DB to replicator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $POSTGRES_DB TO replicator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA $POSTGRES_DB TO replicator;
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;

postgresql.conf:
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = replica
max_wal_senders = 5
max_replication_slots = 10
wal_keep_size = 64

Replica server
postgresql.conf:
listen_addresses = '*'

Common configuration
For testing purposes both servers are using the same content for pg_hba.conf, enabling any connection for both databases:
# Allow replication connections from any host
host    replication     replicator     0.0.0.0/0     trust
host    replication     replicator     ::/0          trust

# Other connections
host    all             all            0.0.0.0/0     md5
host    all             all            ::/0          md5

pg_basebackup and Error
pg_basebackup is being executed in the replica server to request a backup of the primary server:
pg_basebackup -h $REPLICATE_FROM -D $PGDATA -U $PGUSER -vP --wal-method=stream -S replication_slot_slave1

The log file on the primary container shows the error below:

FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host
"10.0.1.109", user "replicator", no encryption

The log file on the replica container shows the error below:

pg_basebackup: error: connection to server at "pg_primary"
(10.0.1.108), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for
replication connection from host "10.0.1.109", user "replicator", no
encryption



Are you sure this is the pg_hba.conf file in use for the servers? 2) Did you reload the file server after making files changes? Add answers as text update to question text.


@AdrianKlaver That is it. Thank you. Please write the solution below telling that I should double check the PostgreSQL configuration files because they can be overriden during the server initialization using the official PostgreSQL docker image. There a lot of solutions in StackOVerflow to overcome this problem.
